# retrieve all datagrid rows in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a datagrid as follows;

mainWindow.xaml:

```
    <DataGrid Name="CSVDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="20,5,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" SelectionChanged="CSVDataGrid_SelectionChanged" Width="560">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Project}" Header="Project" Width="50" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" Width="200"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    private void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CSVDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow) CSVDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            if (row != null)
            {
                object[] itemArray = ((System.Data.DataRowView) (row.Item)).Row.ItemArray;
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Row = {0},{1},{3}",
                                              itemArray[0].ToString(),
                                              itemArray[1].ToString(),
                                                                            i));
            }
        }
    }
```

when the user clicks a button, I want to retrieve the data for every row.   Currently this only works for visible rows.  How can I get all the data?

Comment: Can you use ItemsSource of CSVDataGrid with just casting each item in IEnumerable(ItemsSource) to desired type(System.Data.DataRowView)?

Comment: The `ItemsSource` is all the data. No need for the winforms approach.

Comment: It's returning System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView, but can't see how to get at the individual items for a specific row and column

Comment: tried IEnumerable<CSVData> row = CSVDataGrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<CSVData>; but still comes back null

Comment: @Jim best comment ever.